# Get address for an array element

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm developing a C program and I have a question about pointers and arrays.

I have the following <strike>array</strike> pointer:

```
GLuint *vboIds;
```

And the following function prototype:

```
void glGenBuffers(GLsizei n, GLuint *buffers);
```

The following statement is correct:

```
glGenBuffers(1, vboIds);
```

But I want to pass to `glGenBuffers` the second index of vboIds as second parameter for the function. I have put this:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &&vboIds[1]);
```

Is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: "I have the following array: `GLuint *vboIds;`" Wrong, you have the following **pointer**.  Remember, arrays != pointers, there is an extra layer of indirection with pointers using array notation.

Comment: @SiegeX: I have not worked with C for many years and I have forgotten almost everything.

Comment: Don't worry, this is the most common mistake that C programmers make, even those who have been at it for quite some time. To expand upon the "extra layer of indirection", assume you have declared `int foo[10]; int *bar = foo;`.  When you do `foo[2] = 1;` the address of the array `foo` is a known constant and `2 * sizeof(int)` is added to the address of foo to obtain the value.  On the other hand, when you do `bar[2] = 1;` the first thing that has to happen is a fetch for the value of `bar`, deference that value to get to the array and then add `2 * sizeof(int)` to get the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
glGenBuffers(1, &(vboIds[1]));
```

or what Armen said,

```
glGenBuffers(1, vboIds + 1);
```

Comment: That 1 you add to vboIds address would be valid with any vboIds' type. If I change its type to GLfloat, it would be valid?

Comment: It will always add a byte count equal to the size of the type `vboIds` is pointing at, whether that is `GLUint` or `GLfloat`.

Comment: or glGenBuffers(1,&(1[vboIds]) ); :P

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it would be correct if you remove one ampersand.

You could also write `glGenBuffers(1, vboIds + 1);`.

Comment: Well, I made a mistake that I corrected in 10 seconds. In the meanwhile, someone gave me a downvote...

Answer (score 1):

```
glGenBuffers(1, vboIds + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the double & is incorrect, and will not compile.  If you do want to use that syntax, it's:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vboIds[1]);
```

This is completely equivalent to Armen's answer, which is the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one address of operator (&)

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vboIds[1]);
```